# Setting the current position of turtle as origin

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was trying to make a program which will draw a pie chart, and I want to know how to set the current position of the turtle as 0,0. Like if the position is (90,60) i want (90,60) to be (0,0) without changing the position of the turtle

I tried googling and asking chat gpt but the only anser i got is to use `goto` or `setposition`
but that would change the position of the turtle and I don't want that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is clunky, but I suppose you could do:

```py
origin_x = origin_y = 0

def move_turtle(x, y):
    t.goto(origin_x + x, origin_y + y)

def set_origin(x, y):
    origin_x = x
    origin_y = y
```